# How should I escape or write a session variable names in a PHP eval()?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, session, eval

So admitting that :

```
$gp_splice2 = ['player2']['incoming_armor_loss']
$_SESSION'player2']['incoming_armor_loss'] = 4;
```

why doesn't the following :

```
eval("\$value = \$_SESSION".$gp_splice2.";");
```

come to affect $value with the integer 4???

Ironically

```
eval('echo "\$value = \$_SESSION".$gp_splice2.";";');
```

will happily cause the script to output the following line:

```
$value = $_SESSION['player2']['incoming_armor_loss'];
```

which is the simple code I want the eval to execute, while it doesn't.

And before you get smart, no,avoiding the eval through simply doing this :

```
$value = ${$session_variable_name) (where $session_variable_name = "_SESSION['you_get']['the_idea'])
```

DOESN'T affect $value with what's in `$_SESSION['you_get']['the_idea']`;
The last paragraph is particular to session variables it seems...

Comment: I know it looks like quite some extra code for a simple thing, but the game i'm creating works with TOKENS firing on certain EVENTS and creating a chain reaction, so yeah putting the value we want to retrieve from a player's armor very deep in a dark corner is relevant, while I know in a simpler context such as an rpg it wouldn't be.

Comment: You need to put that in quotes `$gp_splice2 = "['player..."`

Comment: this is not an answer, but it appears that you are missing some punctuation on line 2 of your  first code block.